# My 2D Array is off, need the bottom left corner to be (0,0)

Tags: c++

My code shows a grid of data of

grid[1][1] = 3;

grid[2][1] = 3;

grid[4][5] = 3;

grid[5][6] = 3;

but my display becomes

```
  # # # # # # # # # # #
8 #                   #
7 #                   #
6 #                   #
5 #             3     #
4 #           3       #
3 #                   #
2 #   3               #
1 #   3               #
0 #                   #  
  # # # # # # # # # # #
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

which is wrong

Its somewhat off and i can't get the 2D array to align correctly.
I need the bottom left corner to be (x,y) == (0,0) when i declare the 2D array

What i want is

```
  # # # # # # # # # # #
8 #                   #
7 #                   #
6 #           3       #
5 #         3         #
4 #                   #
3 #                   #
2 #                   #
1 #   3 3             #
0 #                   #  
  # # # # # # # # # # #
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8


#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int ** grid = nullptr;

void initGrid(int col, int row);
void populateGrid(int col, int row);
void safelyDeallocateMemory (int col, int row);

int main() {

    int row = 8
    int col = 8

    initGrid (col, row);
    populateGrid(col, row);
    safelyDeallocateMemory(col, row);
}

void initGrid (int col, int row) {
        grid = new int * [col];

        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++){
            grid [i] = new int [row];
        }

        //Information should stream from text file
        //test

        grid[1][1] = 3;
        grid[4][5] = 3;
        grid[2][1] = 3;
        grid[5][6] = 3;

    }


void populateGrid(int col, int row) {
        cout << "   ";
        //Top outer Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < col + 2; i++) {
            cout << " # ";
        }
        cout << " # ";
        cout << endl;
        //end

        //y-axis
    for (int i = row; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << " " << i << "  #  ";

        //Number of Columns
    for (int j = 0; j <= col; ++j) {
       if (grid[i] == 0 || grid[j] == 0 ||grid[i][j] == 0) {
                cout << "   ";
       }    
       else  {
        cout << grid[i][j] << "  ";
       }    

    }   


    //Right outer Grid
        cout << "   #";
        cout << endl;
    }


    //Last row of #
        cout << "   ";
        for (int i = 0; i < col + 2; i++) {
            cout << " # ";
        }

        cout << " # ";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "       ";

        //x-Axis
        for (int i = 0; i <= col; i++) {
            cout << i << "  ";
        }

        cout << endl;

    }
```

I have tried many variations when declaring the array but it won't work as i intended!

Comment: your array has no notion of "bottom left corner" it just "knows" indices. Simply swap the loop when printing to screen

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j <= col; ++j) if (grid[i] == 0 || grid[j] == 0 ||grid[i][j] == 0) {` -- You are accessing an out-of-bounds element when `j == col`.

Comment: It's beacuse you don't set grid[0][0] that's why there is no bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just treat indexes wrong way.

`grid[2][1] = 3;` is not like `grid[x][y] = 3;`, in your case, but like `grid[y][x] = 3;`.

Imagine it as array of arrays. First index describes position of array in your "array of arrays" and second index describes position in that array.

```
[0] -> [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] <- row 0
[1] -> [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] <- row 1
[2] -> [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] <- row 2
[3] -> [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] <- row 3
[4] -> [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] <- row 4
[5] -> [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] <- row 5
```

It depends on you, how you will treat these indexes.

Ssimple solution to achieve result you want is to change `void initGrid (int col, int row)` this way:

```
void initGrid (int col, int row) {
    grid = new int * [row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        grid [i] = new int [col];
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    //Information should stream from text file
    //test

    grid[1][1] = 3;
    grid[5][4] = 3;
    grid[1][2] = 3;
    grid[6][5] = 3;

}
```

Also you have some troubles with `void populateGrid(int col, int row)`, you are trying to get access to out-of-bound elements in `for (int j = 0; j <= col; ++j)`, so your code should look more like this:

```
void populateGrid(int col, int row) {
    cout << "   ";
    //Top outer Grid
    for (int i = 0; i < col + 2; i++) {
        cout << " # ";
    }
    //cout << " # ";
    cout << endl;
    //end

    //y-axis
    for (int i = row - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << " " << i << "  #  ";

        //Number of Columns
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
                cout << "   ";
            }    
            else  {
                cout << grid[i][j] << "  ";
            }    

        }   


        //Right outer Grid
        cout << "#";
        cout << endl;
    }


    //Last row of #
    cout << "   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < col + 2; i++) {
        cout << " # ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "       ";

    //x-Axis
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        cout << i << "  ";
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```